# document.data gives useless data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is when I print my data it looks like "information = imageurlhere" but I need only "imageurl".Thanks.

```
fun getimages(gelecekid:String){
var collectionref = dbref.collection("sekiller")

var query:Query = collectionref
    .whereEqualTo("aid oldugu elan",gelecekid)
        query.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for (document in documents) {
                    var mydata = document.data
                    mytxtv.setText(mydata.toString())
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: So do you want to extract certain part of the String, that is what i infer? try explaining with real data instead of generic examples.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: In that case, is there a pattern to the string you are getting. What i mean do they all follow some suffix pattern?

Comment: System.out: {aid oldugu elan=9HyuGeXjZuRSkLVZclTW, urlunvani=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kiraye-az.appspot.com/o/images%2F92f032a8-e5ee-41f5-9cd8-4bdaeaaa8711.jpg?alt=media&token=13525a52-5e21-4cff-a853-4149c7752d20}

Comment: this is system out and I need to get only urlunvani

Comment: and what part of this String you want?

Comment: and I need only :  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kiraye-az.appspot.com/o/images%2F92f032a8-e5ee-41f5-9cd8-4bdaeaaa8711.jpg?alt=media&token=13525a52-5e21-4cff-a853-4149c7752d20

Comment: In that case, I would suggest to using split() function with a "urlunvani" as a delimiter.

var string = "your xstring "
var delimiter = "x"

var parts = string.split(delimiter)

results will be "your" and "string". Simply use the 2nd part.

Comment: I solved myself by adding mydata.get("urlunvani").Thanks for your help and patience :D

Comment: No worries, dont forget to accept the answer to promote it for other users :) thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.data` returns a `Map<String, Object>` whose keys are the names of the fields in the document.  You will have to reach into it to get the URL by name of the field. For example:

```
val mydata = document.data
val url = mydata["urlunvani"] as String
```